# Dependency of make_ellipse

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry-generator

I can't find anything on google or the QGIS changelog on this issue:

We're using a style for points which contains a point, a circle and an ellipse.

Point and circle (`buffer($geometry,5,80)`) work fine for everyone, but the ellipse (`make_ellipse($geometry,15*2,15*1.5,135,80)`) don't work for a colleague of mine, neither in QGIS 3.10 nor in 3.4.

Maybe the ellipse has different software dependencies or needs a setting enabled which I forgot about? Has someone an idea?

Comment: It should just work out of the box using the syntax you included in your question. How does it fail for you and your colleague? Do you get an error message in the expression editor?

Comment: It works for me, it just fails for him, as in "the ellipse simply isn't displayed w/o error message". Interestingly, this behaviour got "hardcoded" into the shapefiles he was working with - for those the ellipse didn't show for me also.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the geometry of that shapefile. Have you run the "Check validity" tool (in the "Vector"/"Geometry" menu)?

Comment: Nope, but since they're points and the circle is displayed, I think this highly unlikely.

Comment: Does the shapefile in question contain Multipoint features? In that case, `buffer` would work, but `make_ellipse` would not.

Comment: @Jake that's it. Feel free to post as an answer in order to receive some brass =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make_ellipse` function [does not work on MultiPoint features](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/14d0abc1cef9f5ffdf475f180e2bdc8ca8c62d2c/src/core/expression/qgsexpressionfunction.cpp#L2816-L2817), unlike the `buffer` function. To create ellipses, you first need to convert the MultiPoint layer to single points.

If your layer is MultiPoint but each feature actually only contains a single point, you can also use `make_ellipse(start_point($geometry),15*2,15*1.5,135,80)` to convert the features on the fly within your geometry generator.

Comment: That's a great hack, using `start_point()`to convert single-part multipoints to a single point.